# Flask SelectField float values as choice

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Is it possible to have float values for the SelectField choices?
I tried the following:

```
class RatingForm(Form):

    ratings = [(0.5, 0.5), (1, 1), (1.5, 1.5), 
               (2, 2), (2.5, 2.5), (3, 3), (3.5, 3.5), 
               (4, 4), (4.5, 4.5), (5, 5)]

    rating = SelectField(u'Rate this movie', choices=ratings,
                         validators=[validators.required()], coerce=int)

    def validate(self):
        check_validate = super(RatingForm, self).validate()

        if not check_validate:
            return False

        return True
```

But when I choose a float value the validate check returns false. If I choose an even number(Integer) it works just fine. So is there a way to get float values from the choices options?

Comment: You have the coerce argument set to int. Shouldn't it be a float or something similar considering that you have float values in your choices?

Comment: Ofcourse, thank you :P